# Glue to repair sliced door rubber molding seal?

Tags: door, seal

I loaded some lumber to my SUV and it **sliced** the rubber seal/molding of the hatch door when I was either pushing it inside or pulling it out.

Can I use some sort of glue to glue back together the slice, so that it won't grow bigger? What would be the best glue for this?

Comment: Not sure if the type of rubber will allow this but you might be able to try the rubber cement from a bicycle puncture repair kit, you could also look at using a large patch or boot from a bike repair kit over the cut to prevent it being torn open again

Comment: Superglue should work well.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the soft rubber seal, try something like Shoe Goo. It will mend the two ends together. It will seal them back together so the rubber is still pliable and will still seal. Be careful not to create a large lump at the glue site or you'll create an area where water can leak in (use only as much as you need to get the pieces to stick together). Also, you'll need to leave the hatch open until it is completely cured or it will leave a deformation in the rubber and could possibly adhere to the vehicle body which could rip apart the seal even worse the next time the hatch is opened.